# Viewing the contents of a deleted shell script that is still running

Tags: bash

Another post offered a solution for a self deleting shell script `rm -- "$0"`

If this line is inserted at the top of the script then the script will delete itself as soon as it starts running.

Is it possible to get the contents of the deleted script while it continues to run (meaning a process is still showing up via `ps -eaf | grep scriptname`)?

Comment: `rm` doesn't remove files; it removes file-system entries. The reason the script continues to run is that the process holds an open file handle directly to the inode, rather than continuing to use the file-system entry. You can, I believe, use `lsof` to get the inode for the process's open file handle, then access the inode directly.

Comment: On Linux, you can access files that the process is holding open by looking in `/proc/_pid_/fd`.  I'm not aware of any other way to access a file when you only know the inode number.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92816/can-a-file-be-retrieved-by-its-inode and https://serverfault.com/questions/168909/relinking-a-deleted-file are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can restore the script to its original position. `$pid` contains the PID of your script, e.g. 12345.

```
pid=12345
cat /proc/$pid/fd/255 > "$(readlink /proc/$pid/fd/255 | sed 's/ (deleted)$//')"
```